# Ubuntu file manager is not showing proper icons

Tags: python, icons, filemanager, thumbnails

All files of a code language, particularly python, do not display the proper file icons but instead look like text files - this only happens when the file contains some text.

[image: empty file] [image: file with text]

As you can see the file with no code saved to it `ex18.py` has the proper icon but `ex1.py` has code written to it and the icon looks like a `.txt` file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `mimetype ext18.py; mimetype ex1.py`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `ls -la /usr/share/thumbnailers`

Answer (score 1):

The configuration for the *thumbnailers* for your file manager are in

```
/usr/share/thumbnailers
```

and the binaries are in

```
/usr/bin
```

e.g:

`cat evince.thumbnailer`

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=evince-thumbnailer
Exec=evince-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
MimeType=application/pdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-gzpdf;application/x-xzpdf;application/x-ext-pdf;application/postscript;application/x-bzpostscript;application/x-gzpostscript;image/x-eps;image/x-bzeps;image/x-gzeps;application/x-ext-ps;application/x-ext-eps;application/x-dvi;application/x-bzdvi;application/x-gzdvi;application/x-ext-dvi;image/vnd.djvu;application/x-ext-djv;application/x-ext-djvu;image/tiff;application/x-cbr;application/x-cbz;application/x-cb7;application/x-cbt;application/x-ext-cbr;application/x-ext-cbz;application/x-ext-cb7;application/x-ext-cbt;application/oxps;application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument
```

1. Identify the thumbnailer configuration for the mimetype

   ```
   text/x-python
   ```

   via

   ```
   grep -r 'text/x-python' /usr/share/thumbnailers
   ```

   or only the file name of the thumbnailer configuration with

   ```
   grep -ro 'text/x-python' /usr/share/thumbnailers | awk -F: '{print $1}'
   ```
2. Disable the thumbnailer configuration via

   ```
   grep -ro 'text/x-python' /usr/share/thumbnailers | awk -F: '{system("sudo chmod o-r " $1)}'
   ```
3. Enable via (now you need `sudo`)

   ```
   sudo grep -ro 'text/x-python' /usr/share/thumbnailers | awk -F: '{system("sudo chmod o+r " $1)}'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, check this out : [Icons for source code files are not proper in Ubuntu file manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/733138/icons-for-source-code-files-are-not-proper-in-ubuntu-file-manager)

Did you try  `sudo rm -rf ~/.thumbnails/* ~/.cache/thumbnails/*`

These files are generated automatically. Please post an answer to this question if the above did not work.