# Icons for source code files are not proper in Ubuntu file manager

Tags: icons, filemanager

Recently, I noticed that when I create an empty new file for source code (like .cpp or .hpp or .py) the initial icon is properly shown.
However, as soon as I edit the file by adding some text and saving it, the icon changes to show to something which shows the beginning characters of the file contents. An example of such icons are given below:

[image: improper icons]

Is it possible to prevent this icon change?

Note that I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

---

A similar question is asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676876) but the answer does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Nautilus (the File manager), Edit > Preferences > Preview tab and set Show thumbnails to never. But it will disable preview for images and videos too.

[image]

Since Ubuntu 14.04, the Nautilus version does not allow to disable preview for text files only.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is this a bug in Nautilus?

Comment: This is not a bug, just a choice to simplify the configuration of the user's point of view.