# Nautilus and Nemo don't recognize python 3 files

Tags: python, nautilus, icons, mime-type, nemo

Nautilus and Nemo use two different icons for python files:

[image: Two different icons for python files]

But I want them to show the python icon for all python files.

**mimetype** gives the same result for both files:

```
$ mimetype *.py
buy_test.py:         text/x-python
candlestick_test.py: text/x-python
```

**file -i** gives different outputs:

```
$ file -i buy_test.py 
buy_test.py: text/x-python; charset=us-ascii
$ file -i candlestick_test.py 
candlestick_test.py: text/x-objective-c; charset=us-ascii
```

The output for *candlestick_test.py* is wrong but this file is shown with the python icon. No idea why.

Somebody here had the same problem:
[Ubuntu file manager is not showing proper icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676876/ubuntu-file-manager-is-not-showing-proper-icons)

But the answer he got, doesn't work for me:

```
$ grep -r 'text/x-python' /usr/share/thumbnailers
```

No output.

I think the main diffenrence between these python files is the shebang:

```
$ head -n2 buy_test.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
$ head -n2 candlestick_test.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
```

When I use this shebang (python 2) ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

... there is a python icon, too.

How do Nautilus and Nemo choose file icons?

EDIT:

Some additional information:

There is a python icon if I use one of these shebangs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/usr/bin/python
```

There is **no** python icon if I use one of these shebangs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

So it looks like python3 is a problem.

EDIT 2:

**xdg-mime query filetype FILENAME** returns the MIME type matching the shebang:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype buy_test.py 
text/x-python3

$ xdg-mime query filetype candlestick_test.py 
text/x-python
```

And when I change **candlestick_test.py**'s file extension to **.py3**, the python icon disappears and **xdg-mime query filetype** returns **text/x-python3**.

EDIT 3:

I found a new source of information:

```
$ gio info ~/python/buy_test.py | grep icon
  standard::icon: text-x-python3, text-x-generic
  standard::symbolic-icon: text-x-python3-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic, text-x-python3, text-x-generic
$ gio info ~/python/candlestick_test.py | grep icon
  standard::icon: text-x-python, text-x-generic
  standard::symbolic-icon: text-x-python-symbolic, text-x-generic-symbolic, text-x-python, text-x-generic
```

So I guess, I have to link **text-x-python3** files to **text-x-python** icons somehow.

Comment: Thanks for editing! I'm not yet allowed to embed images.

Comment: Don't think a shebang matters per se, here as long as python is in the file (or in near top?) it gets the icon. Ex, a empty text file named 1.py = no icon. Add just #python  or python to it = icon.

Comment: My first example (buy_test.py) does have "python" within its first line but no icon. The other file has no "python" in its first line but there is a python icon. If I use just "#python" instead of "#!/usr/bin/env python3", I can't run my script via ./buy_test.py anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I could fix it!

As far as I understand, Nemo and Nautilus try to load a file named **text-x-python3.svg** from **/usr/share/icons/[MyTheme]/mimes/[ActualIconSize]/**.
If there is such a file in **~/.local/share/icons/[MyTheme]/mimes/[ActualIconSize]/** it has a higher priority. But none of these directories existed for my theme: *Humanity-Dark*.

So Nemo/Nautilus try to find that icon in another theme.  In **/usr/share/icons/Humanity-Dark/index.theme** is defined which theme to try next:

```
$ grep Inherits /usr/share/icons/Humanity-Dark/index.theme 
Inherits=Humanity,Adwaita,hicolor
```

Next try is *Humanity*. There are icons for *text-x-python* but not for *text-x-python3*. So I did:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/icons/Humanity-Dark/mimes/48
cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/text-x-python.svg ~/.local/share/icons/Humanity-Dark/mimes/48/text-x-python3.svg
```

Same for icon sizes 16 and 22. Now it looks as expected:

[image: Python icons as expected]

Maybe this solution is helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I had a nearly identical problem in Thunar. I had a slightly different solution. I'm using the elementary Xfce icon theme, so change the commands below as appropriate:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/mimes/32/text-x-python.png /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/mimes/32/text-x-python3.png
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/mimes/48/text-x-python.png /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/mimes/48/text-x-python3.png
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/mimes/64/text-x-python.png /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/mimes/64/text-x-python3.png
sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*
```

The last command to refresh the icon cache was necessary for me to see the changes in Thunar. After running the commands above I simply refreshed the directory in Thunar and everything was working as expected.